# Check domain name of email Id for google oauth

Tags: c#, google-oauth

I am trying to authenticate my app using google oauth. I want to allow only a particular set of people having a specific "@eg.com" to be able to obtain access.

I tried including the

```
 hd="eg.com"
```

in my url. 
But it is accepting even "@gmail.com" or "@company.com" domains.
Is there a way to do this, so that users like "users@eg.com" only gain access tokens and stuff?

Edit:
I am using a webview in my app to perform the authorization

Comment: A post-authentication step would be useful. Just deny access to authenticated users without that email domain.

Comment: Can you give details on that? @PatrickHofman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and should!) validate your id_token with a call to the google api. Call `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123` and check the various fields of the response. If you request the "profile" permission you will also get the `email` field. You can then check this email against your domain, and deny the access if it does not fit.

For detailed documentation see: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint

Comment: thanks a lot. This will resolve my problem. But it needs an extra http request, right? I guess there is no other way!

Comment: I'm not sure, what platform you client is on, but for instance on Android you get the email address also in the `GoogleSignInResult` which would not require an additional http request

Answer (score 0):

i think you will have to implement that in your application
just don't store the tokens and show some error message if the domain part is not the one allowed.

you can get the domain part in c# using

```
string s = "users@eg.com";
string[] words = s.Split('@');
```

`words[0]` would be `users` and `words[1]` would be `eg.com`

Alternatively you can use [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. But when the user email is typed in http://google/serviceLogin page, how can I get the email Id?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do and whether the input email is already sanitised, but in this answer `words[1]` may be unexpected on an input like: `test@eg.com@gmail.com`

Comment: @hyoyin_Kyuoma after the auth, the returned object will have the email address

Comment: @PetrusTheron thats an invalid email address, so google auth wont work !